# No action sent when NSSearchField is emptied?

Tags: cocoa, ibaction, nstoolbar, nssearchfield

I've set up an `NSSearchField` in a `toolbar` and connected an action in `Interface Builder`. This action gets called every time I enter some text, but not when I click the small cross to empty it or I somehow delete the text I just entered. Is this a bug or is it fixable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out it actually works. My problem was that 1) I used the search string from the search field to filter some strings and searching a string for an empty string (@"") apparently returns no result 2) when I tried to log the search string using `NSLog(@"%@",searchString)` I got some output only with a non-empty string, while `NSLog(@"sometexthere %@",searchString)` seems to work!